# How can I do non-blocking events processing on Android?

Tags: android, events, java-native-interface, message-queue, looper

This question is about event handling on Android. It is not specific to c++.

I need to process UI/OS events, without blocking when all events have been processed.

The reason is that the application I am porting is very large and can't easily be rewritten to deal with its own stuff on a worker thread. Instead the application engine asks for UI/OS events to be processed during long-winded operations that would otherwise be blocking.

I have found that ALooper_pollAll(...) doesn't do this for me. If I, for example, create a dialog in my activity and start a long operation, ALooper_pollAll() won't make my dialog appear - it will show only when I return to the main loop (I tested this in onNativeWindowCreated).

The only solution that I have found to almost work is to do an inner loop on the UI thread, by calling the following code through JNI:

```
public class MyActivity extends NativeActivity {

  private Handler _uiEventsHandler = null;

  private Runnable _uiEventsTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
      looper.quit();
      _uiEventsHandler.removeCallbacks(this);    
      _uiEventsHandler = null;
    }
  };

  public void ProcessEvents(int timeout)
  {
    if (_uiEventsHandler==null) {
      Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
      _uiEventsHandler = new Handler(looper);
      _uiEventsHandler.removeCallbacks(_uiEventsTask);    
      //_uiEventsHandler.postDelayed(_uiEventsTask,timeout);    
      _uiEventsHandler.post(_uiEventsTask);    
      try {
        looper.loop();
      } catch (RuntimeException re) { 
        // We get an exception when we try to quit the loop, but the inner loop actually terminates
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is, however, not an optimal solution, because it will not loop until there would be no more events to process (because events may be created during the run of the loop).

During my research I have found that I can get the MessageQueue from the Looper and add an IdleHandler that can quit my inner loop. I haven't tried this yet, there has to be a better way.

*Given the fact that this is the architecture I must stick with, what is a better solution?*

**Update:**

Using the MessageQueue I'm able to achieve what I need:

```
public class MyActivity extends NativeActivity {

  private class IdleHandler implements MessageQueue.IdleHandler {
    private Looper _looper;
    protected IdleHandler(Looper looper) {
      _looper = looper;
    }
    public boolean queueIdle() {
      _uiEventsHandler = new Handler(_looper);
      _uiEventsHandler.post(_uiEventsTask);    
      return(false);
    }
  };

  private boolean _processingEventsf = false;
  private Handler _uiEventsHandler = null;

  private Runnable _uiEventsTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
      looper.quit();
      _uiEventsHandler.removeCallbacks(this);    
      _uiEventsHandler = null;
    }
  };

  public void ProcessEvents()
  {
    if (!_processingEventsf) {
      Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
      looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler(new IdleHandler(looper));
      _processingEventsf = true;
      try {
        looper.loop();
      } catch (RuntimeException re) { 
        // We get an exception when we try to quit the loop.
      }
      _processingEventsf = false;
    }
  }
}
```

*However, I still would like to know if there is a better solution.*

Comment: Wow. :) I don't thoroughly understand most of it (just started poking Android 2-3 weeks ago), but I can certainly feel that sooner ot later I'll need this stuff myself, too, so I just promptly favorite it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly but have you tried using an IntentService?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

From the docs:

> This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks from an application's main thread. The IntentService class exists to simplify this pattern and take care of the mechanics."

Comment: This is not what I need to do, I need to work on the main thread, and manually control when event processing happens and for how long.